# Django: running a method on all queryset objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to know if the following is possible and if someone could explain how. I'm using [Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/)

I have a model, in that model I have a class called **Product**. Product has method called **is_product_safe_for_user**. It requires the user object and the self (product).

**model.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text="Title of the product.")
    for_age = models.CharField(max_length=2,)

    def is_product_safe_for_user(self, user):
        if self.for_age > user.age
        return "OK"
```

(ignore the syntax above, its just to give you an idea)

What I want to do is run the method for to all of the queryset objects, something like below, but I don't know how...

```
class ProductListWithAge(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    model = Product
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

      Product.is_product_safe_for_user(self,user)

       # then somehow apply this to my queryset

        return Product.objects.filter()
```

there will also be times when I want to run the methoud on just one object.

**Or should it go into the Serializer? if so how?...**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    safe = serializers.Field(Product='is_product_safe_for_user(self,user)')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'active', 'safe')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) for your model. Something like this:

```
class OnlySafeObjects(models.Manager):
    def filter_by_user(self, user):
        return super(OnlySafeObjects, self).get_query_set().filter(for_age__gte=user.age)

class Product(models.Model):
     # your normal stuff
     onlysafeobjects = OnlySafeObjects()
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
safe_products = Product.onlysafeobjects.filter_by_user(request.user)
```

Comment: so would that mean that if I was to print out all Products that I would have item.onlysafeobjects for each? also how would I pass the user (which is passed in my url)

Comment: The example shows you how to pass the user. A custom manager is like a filter for the entire table. What you access using the manager is already filtered for you. You should read the documentation that I linked for a better idea of what a manager is.